Showing if operator $T-\lambda$ is bounded below for $|\lambda| <1$ then$\lambda \mapsto \dim (\mathcal{H}\ominus (T-\lambda)\mathcal{H})$ is constant
Here's what I am trying to show:
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space. Let $T$ be bounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$ such that $T-\lambda$ is bounded below for each $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\lvert \lambda \rvert < 1$. Show that the function $\lambda \mapsto \dim (\mathcal{H}\ominus (T-\lambda)\mathcal{H})$ is constant on $\{ z \in \mathbb C : \lvert z \rvert < 1 \}$.

I am not sure how to start. All I can see at the moment is that $T-\lambda$ is a semi Fredholm operator for each $\lvert \lambda \rvert < 1$ because it is bounded below but I am not quite sure how it will lead me to conclude what I want.

Clarification:
Given two subspaces $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ of $\mathcal H$, the notation $\mathcal N \ominus \mathcal M$ represents the set of all vectors $n \in \mathcal N$ that are orthogonal to every vector in $\mathcal M$:
$$\mathcal N \ominus \mathcal M = \{ n \in \mathcal N \mid \langle n, m \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } m \in \mathcal M \}.$$

What does the notation $\ominus$ mean, if I may ask?

@BrunoB I guess $\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I).$

@BrunoB Apologies, I was under the impression that $\ominus$ is standard notation. Given two subspaces $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{N}$ of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, $\mathcal{N} \ominus \mathcal{M}$ is set of all vectors $n \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $n \perp \mathcal{M}$, that is, $\langle n, m \rangle$ for each $m \in \mathcal{M}$.
As Ryszard Szwarc correctly points out, $\mathcal{H} \ominus (T-\lambda) \mathcal{H} = \ker (T^* - \overline{\lambda} I)$ which is a consequence of the definition.

I have added a straightforward proof, hopefully correct.

Every operator $T-\lambda I,$ $|\lambda|<1$ is injective and its range is closed.  Hence $T-\lambda I$ is a semi Fredholm operator. According to this the index is locally constant. Therefore the index of $T-\lambda I$ is constant. In the OP case the index is equal $-\dim\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I).$ Therefore $\dim\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$ is constant.
It is possible to prove the claim, with no reference to the index theory.
Assume $R$ satisfies $\|Rv\|\ge 2c\|v\|,$ $v\in \mathcal{H},$ for some constant $c>0.$
Therefore $R$ is injective and has closed range. Moreover the operator $R^*:R\mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ is invertible. Hence
$$\|R^*w\|\ge 3d\|w\|,\quad w\in R\mathcal H$$  for some constant $d>0.$ Let $\|S-R\|<\min(c,d).$
Then, by the triangle inequalities, we get
$$\|Sv\|\ge c \|v\|,\ v\in \mathcal{H},\quad \|S^*w\|\ge 2d \|w\|,\ w\in R\mathcal{H}$$
and
$$\|R^*w\|\ge d \|w\|,\ w\in S\mathcal{H}$$
Thus $S$ is injective and has closed range. Moreover $S^*$ is injective on $R\mathcal H$ and $R^*$ is injective on $S\mathcal{H}.$ The latter imply that $\dim\ker S^*\le \dim \ker R^*$ as $R^*,$ vanishes on $(R\mathcal)^\perp.$ In the same way we get $\dim\ker S^*\ge \dim \ker R^*$ as $S^*$
vanishes on $(S\mathcal{H})^\perp.$
Applying the above reasoning to $R=T-\lambda_1I$ and $S=T-\lambda_2I$ we conclude
that the value $\dim\ker(T^*-\overline{\lambda}I)$ is locally constant.
